# When saving as a PSD, have a PNG also saved automatically

Tags: png, photoshop-scripting, save

On Photoshop CS5, I had it set up so that whenever I saved a .psd, whether it were through cmd-s or the file menu, it would also save a file as a .png with the same name.

I upgraded to CS6 and now I have no idea how to recreate this. Sadly, or stupidly, I uninstalled CS5 so I can't attempt to troubleshoot that way.

Does anyone know how to do this? I don't want to have to run an action every time I want to save a psd as a png, I want it to happen automatically, every time I save.

I appreciate all and any help here.

Thank you, Jacob

Comment: It had to be some other script. Photoshop is not capable of doing what you describe simply by using the Save or Save As command. Are you certain you didn't have some sort of folder action or something in place?

Comment: How exactly did you do this in CS5? I habe never heard of this.

Comment: KMSTR - see below!  And yes it does Scott, as I learned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create your own script if you want, here's a [simple one](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/776366):

```
main(); 
function main(){ 
    var Name = app.activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, ''); 
    var Ext = decodeURI(app.activeDocument.name).replace(/^.*\./,''); 
    if(Ext.toLowerCase() != 'psd') return; 
    var Path = app.activeDocument.path; 
    var saveFile = File(Path + "/" + Name +".png"); 
    if(saveFile.exists) saveFile.remove(); 
    SavePNG(saveFile); 
} 

function SavePNG(saveFile){ 
    pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions(); 
    activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE); 
}
```

- To use this go to File > Scripts > Scripts Event Manager
- Tick "Enable Events to Run Scripts/Actions"
- Select "Save Document" from the Photoshop Event dropdown
- In the next dropdown box select your new script and click add.

Now every time you do a save, the script will check if you are saving it as a PSD, if it is, it will save a PNG with the same name to the same location.

Note: this will overwrite an existing PNG if there is already one in the save location.

Comment: Since you are doing this as an event triggered action (as opposed to manually running the script on demand), it is good form to PROMPT FOR CONFIRMATION before replacing the file.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.  To clarify for other users, if you don't know.  Save this as a .jsx file to CS6Application/Presets/Scripts/events scripts only/

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it was a PNG and not a JPEG? To save a JPEG every time you save your document, open the Script Events Manager.

[image: Script Events Manager]

Then enable events to run scripts and set up an event to save a JPEG when you save your document.

[image: Script Events Manager]

---

You could probably also set up an Automator Workflow in OS X to watch a folder and duplicate and convert PSDs to PNGs.

But it seems likely that the Script Events Manager method is what you had set up previously.

Comment: So the Save Extra JPEG action is supplied? Could that not be adapted to save as PNG?

Comment: Sure could. Looks like Krazer's built something similar! Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a description to the script too.
Just add it on the top of Krazer's script for example.
Please mind the naming though!
My script was named **Save Extra PNG.jsx**

```
//Name and desciption for Photoshop's Script Events Manager
var begDesc = "$$$/JavaScripts/SaveExtraPNG/Description=This script is designed to be used as a script that runs after a save event. The script will save an extra PNG file next to the saved PSD (only) document. It will overwrite PNG files with the same name WITHOUT ASKING for confirmation. Use it wisely!" // endDesc
var begName = "$$$/JavaScripts/SaveExtraPNG/MenuName=Save Extra PNG" // endName  

...and here goes the rest of the code...
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

This is possible, go to `File -> Save As` or <kbd>CTRL+Alt+S</kbd>, then select the PNG file type and click `Save`.

Comment: You are probably receiving downvotes as your answer does not really address or answer the question sufficiently. What you've described is a very manual process, but OP has asked for an automatic way of doing this.