# Can I edit layered PNGs like I can with Fireworks in Photoshop or any other product?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

I loved this feature of Fireworks but since Fireworks is being discontinued I was wondering whether it's possible in Photoshop or other products.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/50044/how-to-read-fireworks-png-multilayer-files-without-fireworks

Answer (score 1):

No.

Layered PNGs are proprietary to Fireworks.

You could always save the layered PNGs as PSDs for Photoshop though.

Comment: Thanks, the workflow I am trying to replicate is when designing assets for a website, I can press Save in Fireworks and I can refresh my website and see the changes live. With PS, I need to always Save For Web which is slow. I wanted to check there is an easier solution than writing a script.

Comment: This is a useful question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10784/when-saving-as-a-psd-have-a-png-also-saved-automatically/10811#10811

Comment: Fireworks may be being discontinued but it won't suddenly un-install itself from your computer. There are many prospects in the pipeline for Fw, for instance http://tribaloid.com/ so don't switch or stop using the best web design tool out there ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution which I found works well is to write a script for Photoshop that saves a png version on save.

[When saving as a PSD, have a PNG also saved automatically](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10784/when-saving-as-a-psd-have-a-png-also-saved-automatically/10811#10811)